# Assistance and explanation for a xquery on xml issues

Tags: xml, xquery

I am new to XQuery and I can't the following simple query to work:

List Names of students and their mentors.

Where there is a Student XML with studentID and mentorID, InstructorXML with instructorID that matchers mentorID, and finally a Person XML with the names and ID which matches studentID and InstructorID.

```
    $Saxon:> 
    <table border="1" > 
    <tr> <td>Student</td> <td >Mentor</td> </tr>
    {
    for $s in doc("ComS363/Projects/Datasets/Student.xml"),
    $i in doc("ComS363/Projects/Datasets/Instructor.xml"),
    $p in doc("ComS363/Projects/Datasets/Person.xml")
    where $s/MentorID/text() = $i/InstructorID/text()
    and $s/StudentID/text() = $p/ID/text()
    and  $i/InstructorID/text() = $p/ID/text()
    return <tr> <td>{$p/Name/text()}</td> <td>{$p/Name/text()}</td> </tr>
    }
    </table> ;
```

I tried the above code but it doesn't work. Is my problem a syntax issues or a logic issues I need help figuring out and fixing the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your XML source documents. However, your query doesn't make much sense

```
where $s/MentorID/text() = $i/InstructorID/text()
    and $s/StudentID/text() = $p/ID/text()
```

$s/MentorID will only select anything if the outermost element of $s is a MentorID element, while $s/StudentID will only select anything if the outermost element is a StudentID element. It can't be both!

Note also, use of /text() is nearly always bad practice.

I would expect to see something like this, but I am guessing your element names:

```
for $s in doc("ComS363/Projects/Datasets/Student.xml")/Students/Student,
    $i in doc("ComS363/Projects/Datasets/Instructor.xml")/Instructors/Instructor,
    $p in doc("ComS363/Projects/Datasets/Person.xml")/Persons/Person
    where $s/MentorID = $i/InstructorID
    and $s/StudentID = $p/ID
    and  $i/InstructorID = $p/ID
    return <tr> <td>{$p/ID}</td> <td>{$p/Name}</td> </tr>
```